# Cannot start Spark in Docker container

Tags: apache-spark, docker

I'm trying to run a Spark instance using Docker (on Windows) following this explanation: https://github.com/sequenceiq/docker-spark

I was able to:

- Pull the image
- Build the image

  - I had to download the Github repository with the Dockerfile though and specify that in the build command. So instead of `docker build --rm -t sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 .` I had to run `docker build --rm -t sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 /path/to/dockerfile`

However when I try to run the following command to run the container:

`docker run -it -p 8088:8088 -p 8042:8042 -p 4040:4040 -h san
dbox sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0`

I get the error:

> Error response from daemon: Container command '/etc/bootstrap.sh' not found or does not exist.

I tried copying the `bootstrap.sh` file from the Github repository to the `/etc` directory on the VM but that didn't help.

I'm not sure what went wrong, any advice would be more than welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably an issue with the build context because you changed the path to the Dockerfile in your build command.

Instead of changing the path to the Dockerfile in the build command, try cd'ing into that directory first and then running the command. Like so:

```
cd /path/to/dockerfile
docker build --rm -t sequenceiq/spark:1.6.0 .
```

Comment: Good stuff, thought it had something to do with the build process. Thanks. (btw I had to remove and re-create the VM)